# Gradle - Multiple Jar from single project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, executable-jar

**Context:** To create multiple executable jar's from a single project - multiple package gradle project

**Issue:** I refer to the solution provided in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30149040/3127144), this helps in generating the jar in build->libs folder, but when I try executing the jar nothing happens

**Note:** Even if I make the package name same as java file name, the generated jar does not execute.

Also I notice the file size of all the jar's generated is the same. Hope the issue faced is clear & await inputs as to where I am making a mistake.

My Project Structure (illustrative purpose):

```
ProjectA
-src
--main
---java
----pkg1
-----pkgCalculator         
------Calculator.java
-----pkgScale              
------Scale.java
----pkg2
-----pkgMusicPlayer        
------MusicPlayer.java
-----pkgVideoPlayer        
------VideoPlayer.java
---resources
----fxml
----css
--test
---java
---resources
```

**Gradle** file (relevant portion below, rest as per the link above ):

```
artifacts {
    archives jarPackage("pkgCalculator", "1.0"),
            jarPackage("pkgScale","1.0"),
            jarPackage("pkgMusicPlayer","1.0"),
            jarPackage("pkgVideoPlayer","1.0")

}
```

Comment: you should check the content of the produced jar, and make sure that all needed compiled classes are included (in the correct package) and the MANIFEST is there with the right Main-Class attribute

Comment: Tried with jar tvf command on the jar file, but it lists out way too many files & the cant scroll to the start in the terminal also guess it is due to the volume of entries displayed

Comment: just to be sure: did you try to move  class `pkg1.pkgCalculator.Calculator` to `calculator.Calculator`   (remove first-level `pkg1`) ?    and try to extract jar content in order to check  the MANIFEST, there is probably wrong Main-Class attribute value there...

Comment: Tried even that isn't working. Is there a way to pause the screen scrolling when we execute jar tvf , like page wise view or something? For if I execute just that screen scrolls too fast & cant see all things displayed. Checked - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html but couldnt find it

Comment: you need to extract the jar in order to check MANIFEST content :  `jar xf YOUR_JAR`

Comment: the Manifest looks fine contains the version (manifest & implementation) also the title & main class. Nothing appears wrong in it atleast to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181962/discussion-between-m-ricciuti-and-icoder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with @iCoder, first part of the issue has been solved:  the `jarPackage` function could not be reused "as is", and had to be adapted to support generic class/package layout:

```
def jarPackage(String jarName, String className, artifactVersion) {
    if (artifactVersion == "" || artifactVersion == null) {
        artifactVersion = "1.0.0"
    }
    return tasks.create("jar${jarName}", Jar) {
        baseName = jarName

        version = artifactVersion

        def String pkgName = className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf("."))
        def String pkgDir = pkgName.replaceAll("\\.", "/")
        def String clazzName = className.substring( className.lastIndexOf(".") +1 )
        from(sourceSets.main.output) {
            include "$pkgDir//**"
        }

        from {
            configurations.compile.collect {
                it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
            }
        }

        manifest {
            attributes "Implementation-Title": "$clazzName",
                    "Implementation-Version": "$version",
                    "Main-Class": "$pkgName.$clazzName"
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives jarPackage("calculator", "pkg1.pkcalculator.Calculator" , "1.0.0")
}
```

Another issue remains, not related to Gradle but to JDK 11 linkage problem: @iCoder you should open another question for that remaining problem, if not fixed yet.

Comment: once running the jarPackage function in the build, I'm getting the submodules that I need inside an extra jar in the build, but not getting the rest of it's dependenciess such as springboot dependencies.. is there a way to include the rest of my dependencies inside this extra jar?