# Customize Manifest in War task

Tags: java, gradle

I need to modify Manifest file during the assembly of WAR file. I need to add a list of all files on a class path to avoid `java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long`  exception being thrown when I want to execute this java file on Windows machine.

Declared directly in build script this task does the work.

```
task pathingWar(type: War) {
  getArchiveAppendix().set("pathing")
  doFirst {
    manifest {
      attributes "Class-Path": sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { project.uri(it) }.join(" ")
    }
  }
}
```

However I wanted to create a standalone task in **buildSrc** directory like in the code below. War gets created with the pathing appendix in name, but there is no additional `Class-Path` property inside `MANIFEST.MF` file even if `classpathFiles` variable holds required values while debugging the execution of the task.

```
class PathingWar extends War {

   PathingWar() {
    getArchiveAppendix().set("pathing")
  }

  @TaskAction
  def setManifestTask() {
    def classpathFiles = ((SourceSet)((SourceSetContainer) getProject().getExtensions().getByName("sourceSets"))
            .getByName("main")).getRuntimeClasspath().getFiles().collect {project.uri(it)}.join(" ")
    setManifest(getManifest().attributes(["Class-Path": classpathFiles]))
  }
}
```

Attributes won't be set to the Manifest, what did I missed when translating logic from build script to custom task?

**Update**

After further inspection I see that when `setManifestTask()` annotated with `@TaskAction` is being executed is already being too late. At this point war is generated under the `build/libs` folder. I need another way of configuring the manifest. I don't know which other approach to use.

Comment: after this custom class - have you changed build.gradle to have `task pathingWar(type: PathingWar) {`

Comment: exactly in the build script itself task is defined as: `task pathingWar(type: com.crealogix.PathingWar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to set manifest **Class-Path** attribute in the `doFirst{}` block so that it would be set as first action and similar like in the original script without a success. Still **jar** was generated before closure in `doFirst` was executed.

After I read the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16413207/978302
I understood I shouldn't be overriding functionality of a War task. Instead I have to configure it with available inputs and result will be generated behind the scenes.

Final solution doesn't contain any actions defined. Only additional configuration for:

- archivaAppendix
- manifest

Task definition:

```
class PathingWar extends War {

  PathingWar() {
    getArchiveAppendix().set("pathing")
    manifest {
      def classpathFiles = ((SourceSet) ((SourceSetContainer) getProject().getExtensions().getByName("sourceSets"))
              .getByName("main")).getRuntimeClasspath().getFiles().collect { project.uri(it) }.join(" ")
      attributes "Class-Path": classpathFiles
    }
  }
}
```

BTW: I still don't understand why the task defined in script works as expected.